# How to hide console in windows 11

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, console

I wrote a program that should run in the background. I tried to write some codes, but they are all not working. The console is hidden in windows 10, but does not work in version 11. I am using this compiler x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

I am trying to use this code:

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)
```

Then I tried this code, but the result is the same:

```
AllocConsole();
ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), 0);
```

Then I tried this code, but the result is the same:

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(),0);
```

Comment: What is your compiler and build-environment? If you're using Visual Studio (the full IDE, not the VSCode editor) then have you created a WIN32 project or a console project? You should create a WIN32 project to not get the console in the first place. If you use another environment and e.g. GCC then you have to build for the Windows subsystem, otherwise you create a console program as default.

Comment: Try [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole)

Comment: Do you actually want a console, but (dynamically) show and hide it, or do you not want a console at all? The answers will be different. Besides, if you want something to run in the background, consider writing a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services).

Comment: You don't need to do anything in the code. Pass `-mwindows` when linking.

Comment: Build a Windows application (or a service), not a console application.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat don't work. I added this flag but the console still shows

Comment: @RichardCritten don't work in windows 11

Comment: How exactly did you add the flag? What commands did you use for compiling and linking?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Blog: [Windows Terminal is now the Default in Windows 11](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-is-now-the-default-in-windows-11/)

If you used default Windows Terminal, you couldn't hide console.

I suggest you could try to change your terminal to `Windows Console Host` in the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to this post: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/15311, things like `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)` won't work. The methods I found to solve this is to change the way we run the app.

On Windows 11, **Solution 1**

Use *conhost*:

```
conhost C:\path\to\your\app.exe
```

This works well for me. However, the anti-virus could stop it if you make this a desktop shortcut.

**Solution 2**

Use PowerShell:

```
Start-Process "C:\path\to\your\app.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

You can put this in a .bat file if you want:

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process 'C:\path\to\your\app.exe' -WindowStyle Hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the bat file for a long time, I couldn't get anything to work. Everything worked fine in command prompt, but not there.
The solution was simple: `just create a shortcut to conhost "C:\path\to\your\app.exe"` That's it!