Is there any function to close ALL the windows?
I want to write a program that closes all application windows every 30 minutes. All windows. Is there some function in C++ to close all windows and show the desktop? All the windows, running applications, etc. And my program must work in the background.
I tried ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE).
but the window remained open. The console on taskbar too. How can I do this?

What do you mean by "close"? Terminate all the programs? Or do you just want to minimize them, with the same effect that you'd get by clicking in the lower-right corner?

About your second question (why ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE) doesn't work), please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75877438/how-to-hide-console-in-windows-11/78943791#78943791

It's entirely unclear what problem you are trying to some. Please add enough detail to the question so that it can be answered.

To show the desktop, you can simulate pressing Windows + D
//use keybd_event
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, NULL, NULL, NULL);
keybd_event('D', NULL, NULL, NULL);
keybd_event('D', NULL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, NULL);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, NULL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, NULL);

//use SendInput
INPUT WinD[4]{};
WinD[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; WinD[0].ki.wVk = VK_LWIN;
WinD[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; WinD[1].ki.wVk = 'D';
WinD[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; WinD[2].ki.wVk = 'D'; WinD[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
WinD[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; WinD[3].ki.wVk = VK_LWIN; WinD[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(4, WinD, sizeof(INPUT));

But if you want to destroy all windows, that might be a bit difficult.
You have to enumerate all windows and determine whether they should be destroyed.

Instead of simulating keyboard input (which can be troublesome, e.g. if the user happens to be holding the Shift or Ctrl key at the time you simulate the input), use the API: Shell.MinimizeAll: "This method has the same effect as right-clicking the taskbar and selecting Minimize All Windows on older systems or clicking the Show Desktop icon in the Quick Launch area of the taskbar in Windows 2000 or Windows XP."

You can make a request for all top-level windows to close with one, simple API call – just post the WM_CLOSE message (using the HWND_BROADCAST token as the 'window handle') to the system:
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);

Reference: PostMessage and WM_CLOSE
Assuming the target windows (and their owning applications) don't do anything weird, then the applications (if they behave normally) will close any children and other 'owned' windows.

This is obviously a bad idea.
When you do this, you also close a lot of windows that shouldn't be closed, including your own programs themselves.
Generally speaking, when you need to broadcast a message to "all" windows, it definitely means something is wrong.
Have you actually tried executing this command on your computer?

@許恩嘉 (1) I'm not saying it is a good idea, just that it does what (I think) the OP is asking. (2) If the source program isn't window-based (i.e. it runs like a sort of 'service), then it won't be affected. But, reading the Q again, it is possible that the OP doesn't really want to close the other windows but just to minimize or hide them - which is a rather trickier problem.

Regardless of what the OP really wants, doing this will seriously affect the operation of the system.
There are many invisible windows that support the functioning of the system and should not be closed.

WM_CLOSE is a request, not a command. It's not crazy at all for an application to deny that request or fire up a confirmation dialog.

One could broadcast WM_QUIT instead of WM_CLOSE.  Still not a good idea, but it is an option.

Probably better to use EnumWindows() and selectively close/hide only windows that the user can actually see.
